# Is the 1.7.10 Hammer Time mod compatible with Minecraft 1.8?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I can only find a 1.7.10 version of the [Hammer Time Mod](http://niceminecraft.net/hammer-time-mod/), but I'm playing 1.8.

Is 1.7.10 version compatible with Minecraft 1.8? Or is there a 1.8 version somewhere?

Comment: While the site you used is not *that bad*, please [do not download mods from rehosters](http://stopmodreposts.org/). They are parasitic sites profiting off the work of others without their consent. The Hammer Time! mod is officially hosted on Curse: http://mods.curse.com/mc-mods/minecraft/237695-hammer-time

Answer (score 2):

No, you're not able to use a 1.7 mod in 1.8 because they're major updates. This story changes with minor updates, especially in 1.9 versions, where you're able to use some 1.9 mods with 1.9.1.

Comment: While this may be used as a guess, this is not the rule at all. Even minor updates may happen to change the exact code the mod is modifying, and then boom.

Comment: At https://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/hammer-time the mod creator stated that it would be available for 1.8 when he could figure out a way to port the models.